# Fragment displays wrong menu items

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem

For unknown reason sometime my fragment is showing menu items that belongs to a different fragment.

I have a single activity with custom back stack to maintain the correct flow using:

```
 Map<Integer, List<Fragment>> fragmentStack = new HashMap<>();
```

This way each "tab" has its own backstack.
I am switching between the fragments with:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
    .commitNow();
```

The fragments are maintained in the Map, so when switching to existing fragment I use it's already initialized view.

Sometimes when I switch from one fragment to second fragment, the second fragment displays menu items from a previously created fragment in the stack despite the fact that *onCreateOptionsMenu* is called correctly on the second fragment.
 How do I overcome this unwanted behavior?

The actions that lead to this behavior:

 1. Starting at first tab. Map initialized at key 0, with `List<fragment>` with one fragment, called A. This fragment then displayed. (fragment A has menu items) 
 2. Navigating to second tab. Map initialized at key 1, with `List<fragment>` with one fragment, called B, this fragment displayed (replacing fragment A). Fragment B also has menu items. 
 3. Navigating back to first tab. Previous fragment A is used including it's already initialized view (not inflating a new one). 
 4. Clicking something with navigates to a new fragment C staying at the same tab. fragment C is added to the fragment list, under the key 0 of the Map. fragment C has no menu items.

 5. Navigating to second tab. Previous fragment B is displayed but with menu items of fragment A!

Comment: are you using fragments in ViewPager?

Comment: @rupinderjeet No, I am using bottom navigation view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem eventually.
The fragment's onCreateView looked this way:

```
if (rootView == null) {
// Init view logic and inflation, and:
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
return rootView;
```

moving the `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` outside the if statement fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check onCreateOptionsMenu is called for all fragment or not.

Comment: It is called, and the correct menu is inflated for each fragment. However the fragment still displays the wrong items. When debugging the wrong menu item are visible even before hitting the onCreateOptionsMenu